# openvpn SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting

Tags: debian, openvpn

I have this error on `OpenVPN` client (Debian 6):

```
Apr 12 09:36:41 example ovpn-server[32093]: Attempting to establish TCP   connection with [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 [nonblock]
Apr 12 09:36:42 example ovpn-server[32093]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Apr 12 09:36:42 example ovpn-server[32093]: TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Apr 12 09:36:42 example ovpn-server[32093]: TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Apr 12 09:36:42 example ovpn-server[32093]: Connection reset, restarting [-1]
Apr 12 09:36:42 example ovpn-server[32093]: TCP/UDP: Closing socket 
Apr 12 09:36:42 example ovpn-server[32093]: SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Apr 12 09:36:42 example ovpn-server[32093]: Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

On the server log I get:

```
TCP connection established with [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:37452
Apr 12 10:45:50 server ovpn-server[23502]: TCPv4_SERVER link local: [undef]
Apr 12 10:45:50 server ovpn-server[23502]: TCPv4_SERVER link remote: [AF_INET]xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:37452
Apr 12 10:45:51 server ovpn-server[23502]: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:37452 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:37452, sid=da69d896 fd84d999
Apr 12 10:45:51 server ovpn-server[23502]: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:37452 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
Apr 12 10:45:51 server ovpn-server[23502]: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:37452 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
Apr 12 10:45:51 server ovpn-server[23502]: TCP/UDP: Closing socket
```

Can you please help me to find the solution and make it work ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2):

port 443 was filtered, that was the issue.

Comment: How would you go about fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

This error could also happen if the OpenVPN server clock is not correct. 
Mine was showing 1970 (an old router whose clock battery probably died), and after updating it I was able to connect to the OpenVPN server.